# div onclick issue with basic "LightsOut" script

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I'm just developing my skills and trying to create a js app to do the "Lights Out game" type of script that you might have seen before. Nothing complicated. Or so I thought. The idea is you start out with a grid of darkened lights, and if you click one button it toggles the state of the clicked button as well as those to the NSEW of that button. Once you click the correct sequence, all the lights are lit. My problem is basically that the divs I created are not registering a click event.

```
function lightUp(){
$("div.light").click(function(){
    var thisDiv = $(this).attr("id");
    var topDiv = null;
    var bottomDiv = null;
    var leftDiv = null;
    var rightDiv = null;
    for (i= 1; 4; i++){
        for (j=1; 4; j++){
            var testDiv = "r"+i+"c"+j;
            if (testDiv === thisDiv) {
                if (i > 1) {
                    topDiv = "r"+(i-1)+"c"+j;
                }
                if (i < 4) {
                    bottomDiv = "r"+(i+1)+"c"+j;
                }
                if (j > 1) {
                    leftDiv = "r"+i+"c"+(j-1);
                }
                if (j < 4) {
                    rightDiv = "r"+i+"c"+(j+1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    $("#"+thisDiv, "#"+topDiv, "#"+bottomDiv, "#"+leftDiv, "#"+rightDiv).toggleClass("on").toggleClass("off");

});
                     }
```

is not registering the clicks on the divs.

```
<div id="r2c3" class="light off" onclick="lightUp();"></div>
```

It's possible this kind of script has to be much more complex, but I'm trying it out. Input is appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/4bUnt/3/

Comment: For starters.. You are combining javascript and jquery and not including jquery library.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4bUnt/4/ applying a jquery framework on jsfiddle has no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, got it working for you.  Check it out here:

http://jsfiddle.net/4bUnt/6/

Normally when giving an answer I would propose the solution and let the person re-work their code, however in this case their were quite a few syntax errors and various problems with the code, that to try to point them out one by one, step by step would have been quite cumbersome and the back and forth dialog in comments would have been too much.  Maybe is why there is no other answers to this question so far..  anyway, check it out and learn from it and if you found this and a solution and/or helpful answer, please select this as the answer or up-vote it.  thank you.  Carry on. Good luck!  :)

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$("div.light").click(function(){
    var thisDiv = $(this).attr("id");
    var topDiv = null;
    var bottomDiv = null;
    var leftDiv = null;
    var rightDiv = null;
    for (var i= 1; i<5; i++){
        for (var j=1; j<5; j++){
            var testDiv = "r"+i+"c"+j;
            if (testDiv === thisDiv) {
                if (i > 1) {
                    topDiv = "r"+(i-1)+"c"+j;
                }
                if (i < 4) {
                    bottomDiv = "r"+(i+1)+"c"+j;
                }
                if (j > 1) {
                    leftDiv = "r"+i+"c"+(j-1);
                }
                if (j < 4) {
                    rightDiv = "r"+i+"c"+(j+1);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if ($("#"+thisDiv).hasClass("off")) {
        $("#"+thisDiv).removeClass("off").addClass("on");
        $("#"+topDiv).removeClass("off").addClass("on");
        $("#"+bottomDiv).removeClass("off").addClass("on");
        $("#"+leftDiv).removeClass("off").addClass("on");
       $("#"+rightDiv).removeClass("off").addClass("on");
    } else {
        $("#"+thisDiv).removeClass("on").addClass("off");
        $("#"+topDiv).removeClass("on").addClass("off");
        $("#"+bottomDiv).removeClass("on").addClass("off");
        $("#"+leftDiv).removeClass("on").addClass("off");
       $("#"+rightDiv).removeClass("on").addClass("off");
     }

});
```

});

Comment: Thank you for your help. You were very close to my design. I have updated the fiddle if you're interested in how it was supposed to look. http://jsfiddle.net/4bUnt/7/

Comment: Awesome Elijah!  It's a cool little game and great project idea!  I see to got it working better as intended. Best of luck.  :)